# Play 2.0 routing not working with long?

Tags: routes, playframework, url-routing, playframework-2.0

I have a route defined like this:

```
GET     /question/:q_id             controllers.Questions.viewQuestion(q_id: Long)
```

Then in my controller I have this:

```
public static Result viewQuestion(long q_id) {
    System.out.println("made it here");
    return ok(ViewQuestion.render(Question.findById(q_id)));
}
```

However, I the `println` never gets called and a completely blank page is served. Any clues as to what might be happening?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `controller.` part of the route?

Comment: Actully I think I just fixed, it was a Scala-> Java issue, when I changed the arguments to `viewQuestion()` form `long` to `Long` it began to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error appeared to be due to a conversion between the Scala `Long` type and the Java `long` type.

I fixed this by chaining my viewQuestion() method:

```
public static Result viewQuestion(Long q_id) {
    long id = (long) q_id;
    //do stuff with id 
    ...
}
```

I guess I need to learn more about how Scala and Java interact...

Comment: I don't think that Scala uses the primitive long as java but actually uses the class Long instead. That's why your conversion did not work.